# Please can somebody explain this short and sweet javascript code

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
var x=1

if(x){
  x=0;
}
if(x){
  x=1
};
alert(x);
```

Can't get my head around why is it 0.

Comment: Really you think that the title and body of this question will allow other visitors to find a useful piece of knowledge?

Answer (score 7):

With

```
var x=1
```

`x` starts out truthy. This means the first `if` is fulfilled:

```
if(x){x=0;}
```

making `x` falsey (0), so the second `if` does not run

```
if(x){
```

so, at the end, `x` is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var x=1

if(x){ // x is 1 here condition success
  x=0; // so x is assigned as 0
}                                                                                                                                
if(x){ // so here x is 0 so condition fails
  x=1
};
alert(x); // then it alerts 0
```

Answer (score 2):

First x is truthy (1) so the first if statement is run, and it's made 0. This is falsy, so the second if statement is skipped and the value of x (0) is alerted.

Answer (score 2):

1. Control reaches to the logic inside an `if` statement if the value inside a bracket is `truthy`.
2. All values are truthy unless they are defined as `falsy`.
3. Folks above have beautifully explained what are the different types of `falsy` values.

So, in the end, it turns out to be 0.

I think had that statement been something like.

`if (x === 1) { // some code }`

it would have made more sense. Just need to think over why the above code works and things will make sense.

Answer (score 2):

So here's my take on explaining what I understood.
Here we are assigning value 1 to variable x.

```
var x=1
```

Next, we are checking the value of x.

```
 if(x)
    {
      x=0;
    }
```

Here `if(x)` condition will be asserted as true if variable x is either :

- assigned and initialized
- not null
- not undefined
- not empty
- greater than 0
- is a number
- true

So x=1, hence, it assigns the value 0 to x.
Now in next condition, x will be equal to 0. So, the condition is not asserted as true. And x will not be assigned value 1.
Hence, you get the alert as 0.
I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is, 'Coercion' in Javascript.
When we use one type of Javascript variable in a place/function/condition etc. where some other type of variable is expected, the Javascript does not throw an error. Instead, it changes that variable's value to that specific type of variable. Its called coercing.

For Example:

```
var a = "" ;
if (a){                     //a is coerced to false
  console.log (true);
}
else{
console.log (false);
}
```

In the above code, the null string is coerced to false.

Similarly, in your code, coercing is happening:

```
var x=1

if(x){      // x is coerced to true, this condition is met and x is set to 0.
  x=0;
}
if(x){     // since x is 0, it is coerced to false, so condition is not satisfied
  x=1
};
alert(x);
```

For further details, checkout this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/).

Answer (score 1):

There are 6 falsy values in JavaScript.

- false
- 0
- "", '', `` (Length of String)
- null
- undefined
- NaN

```js
console.log('Is truthy: ', isTruthy(false));
console.log('Is truthy: ', isTruthy(0));
console.log('Is truthy: ', isTruthy(undefined));
console.log('Is truthy: ', isTruthy(null));
console.log('Is truthy: ', isTruthy(NaN));
console.log('Is truthy: ', isTruthy(""));
console.log('Is truthy: ', isTruthy(''));
console.log('Is truthy: ', isTruthy(``));

function isTruthy(v) {
  if(v) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

For more information, you can refer to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

**The explanation of your code:**

```
var x=1

if(x) { // x is 1 = truthy
  x=0; // x is now 0
}                                                                                                                                
if(x) { // x is 0 = falsy (as per above explanation)
  x=1
};
alert(x); // alert 0
```

Hope this may help you.